# Connecting to a remote Postgres 9.1 DB

Tags: postgresql-9.1, ubuntu, remote

I am running Postgres 9.1 on Ubuntu.
I have `host all all my.ip.address/32 md5`
set in pg_hba.conf and `listen_addresses= '*'` set in postgresql.conf.
Running `show listen_addresses` shows '*'
Running `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep postgres` shows

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28899/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      28899/postgres
```

However, I sill cannot connect to the DB using pgAdmin III on my machine that is located at "my.ip.address". 
What could I have missed in the set up?

Thank you.

Comment: What error message do you get in Pgadmin ? What if you try psql -h your.server.ip -U youruser -d yourdatabase -W from your client machine ? Is there any firewall inbetween ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it made me realize one thing I did NOT check. The problem turned out to be a blocked OUTGOING port on my network. Thank you for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the following two files

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Make sure to restart postgres service after changing the files.

You have to check if the port 5432 is open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

If it's not then add a rule to your `iptables`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

0/0: If you want anybody to access it.
You can change it to a specific IP address or range of IP addresses.